# Javascript extract date from certain elements with match and regex returns empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, userscripts

I want to make a userscript for a website, where I want to extract and select the date in some `<td>` fields.
Example:

```
<tbody>
<td><img></td>
<td>something</td>
<td>something</td>
...
<td style="text-align:center;">2016-02-10 13:27</td>
<td>something</td>
...
<td>something</td>
</tbody>
```

There are two things I want to do:
1. compare the date with another stored date (and check if it is later).
2. change the background-color of the `<td>` element where the date is located.

This is what I have, and it returns an empty array...

```
var dateArray = [];
$("td").each(function(){
    if(String(this).match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}/)){
        dateArray.push(this);
    }
});
```

What is wrong and/or what could I do in a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess *this* will be a jQuery object, what you do you expect `String(this)` to return? You might try `this.text()` instead (see API doco: [*.text()*](http://api.jquery.com/text/)).

Comment: Yes, it was an object first, that's why I did the `String(this)`, so I could do the `.match` to extract the date

Comment: `String(object)` will call the object's *toString* method. I don't think jQuery sets a specific method, so you'll get the built–in *Object.prototype.toString* , which is probably returning something like *[object Object]*.

Comment: Also note that if you intend converting "2016-02-10 13:27" to a date, then you'll need to parse it manually (a library can help but it only needs a 2 line function). That format isn't one supported by ECMAScript 2015, so parsing is implementation dependent. Some will treat it as UTC, some as local and the rest as invalid.

Comment: You were right about the _[object Object]_ return! Didn't noticed that... Thanks! I also didn't know about the converting problem, have to check that out, good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try to create a date object. And check whether a valid date was created

```
var date = new Date($(this).text());
if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
  // invalid date
} else {
  // valid date
}
```

Comment: Works as a charm, thank you! I changed it to `(!isNaN(date.getTime()))`, because I only need the valid dates.

Comment: Oh, and there is a `)` missing after `(isNaN(date.getTime())`

Comment: Please don't recommend parsing strings with the Date constructor, it's unreliable (to say the least).

Comment: Thanks @RobG I'll keep that in mind